# Is there anyway for netbeans to warn you with audio when it finishes the debug/Clean&Build?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

The project i am working on is pretty big, with each Clean&Build and debug taking a lot of time, is there any way to netbeans to make any kind of sound or pop up, saying that the debug is finished? or the clean&build?

The current version of netbeans i have is 8.1. I appreciate if anyone knows

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are searching but there is a plugin for making sounds when a certain breakpoint is hit: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/56682/beep

Maybe this is already sufficient for you. 
Else writing your own plugin shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: No, this isnt anything like i asked, i asked explicity on debug / clean&Build because of the large time it requires to complete. 
"Else writing your own plugin shouldn't be that hard." I guess writing a book isnt that hard also, but i don't have time to do it

Comment: If you place a breakpoint in your init code, configure your project to always clean&build and hit then debug you would be notified when NetBeans finished your building process and you are ready to debug. But maybe I misunderstood you completely.